# RelativeLayout not showing inside another

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I have these two ImageViews in a header I want header logo in the center and the backbutton on the left. I can't seem to separate them and have them on their own.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#74282c">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/a"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/header_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Remove  android:gravity="center" from your parent relative layout first

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the back Button above the imageview like framelayout so you have to add the button after the logo,

and u have to use ImageButton instead of ImageView for clickable items

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#74282c">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="292dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/header_logo" />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        android:background="@null"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```